# np.dot returns nan for Dataframe(float64) and np.ndarray(fload64)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a squared dataframe containing over 505 rows and columns (a 505x505 matrix)

which I need to `dot` multiply to an ndarray from numpy (505 items).

the problem is that the result is an ndarray with 505 items, full of `nan`.

I tried replicating it on a separate notebook, but I wasn't able to.

in

```
print('df ', df)
print('info ', df.info())
result = np.dot(df, np.random.rand(505))
print('result.shape: ', result.shape)
print('result ', result)
```

out

```
df               A       AAL       AAP      AAPL      ABBV       ABC      ABMD  \
A     0.093188  0.072021  0.048887  0.067503  0.047795  0.052311  0.051706   
AAL   0.072021  0.547093  0.099290  0.069475  0.045120  0.066275  0.065950   
AAP   0.048887  0.099290  0.143932  0.055590  0.043934  0.059230  0.041979   
AAPL  0.067503  0.069475  0.055590  0.140050  0.051688  0.054113  0.060444   
ABBV  0.047795  0.045120  0.043934  0.051688  0.096598  0.047673  0.032663   
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...   
YUM   0.042185  0.095983  0.058538  0.052228  0.036547  0.046676  0.031293   
ZBH   0.054474  0.127670  0.057043  0.054673  0.046718  0.054718  0.053090   
ZBRA  0.079731  0.100945  0.064364  0.091272  0.054140  0.062255  0.066586   
ZION  0.061233  0.176829  0.075915  0.048804  0.044935  0.066857  0.044151   
ZTS   0.060966  0.052413  0.054156  0.069211  0.047445  0.054443  0.041018   
 

          XRAY       XYL       YUM       ZBH      ZBRA      ZION       ZTS  
A     0.053152  0.064197  0.042185  0.054474  0.079731  0.061233  0.060966  
AAL   0.110541  0.125551  0.095983  0.127670  0.100945  0.176829  0.052413  
AAP   0.064716  0.071780  0.058538  0.057043  0.064364  0.075915  0.054156  
AAPL  0.047973  0.067265  0.052228  0.054673  0.091272  0.048804  0.069211  
ABBV  0.049469  0.043552  0.036547  0.046718  0.054140  0.044935  0.047445  
...        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...  
YUM   0.060310  0.059523  0.098728  0.069827  0.051222  0.057302  0.057192  
ZBH   0.084555  0.068429  0.069827  0.136291  0.070115  0.089688  0.058264  
ZBRA  0.068271  0.085070  0.051222  0.070115  0.185910  0.087744  0.069007  
ZION  0.099294  0.098861  0.057302  0.089688  0.087744  0.204927  0.040132  
ZTS   0.052646  0.057712  0.057192  0.058264  0.069007  0.040132  0.095019  

[505 rows x 505 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 505 entries, A to ZTS
Columns: 505 entries, A to ZTS
dtypes: float64(505)
memory usage: 2.0+ MB
info  None
result.shape:  (505,)
result  [nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan]
```

Comment: Have you checked your input 2D and 1D arrays for NaNs?

Comment: well spotted, thanks, I had nans in the df. they were hiding among the 505 columns

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you should use [DataFrame.dot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)

```py
import pandas as pd;
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'])
other = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']).transpose()
```

Notice that the indices of the second `DataFrame` must match the rows of the first, then you can multiply them

```
df.dot(other)
# or
other.dot(df)
```

Remember that the matrix multiplication is not commutative.

If you do `df.dot(other)` it will return a dataframe with the indices of df and the columns of `other`, if you call it with a numpy array it will return a dataframe with columns counting [0,1,2,...]

Comment: thanks but that didn't help, what actually helped was checking for NaNs, found a few columns that had some,

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't get your question right, since the data I generated had no NaN I didn't realize, but in your case you would need to use a [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Comment: my attempt to reproduce didn't have NaN either, and that's what confused me, so many data I couldn't see the NaNs and didn't think there were any.